# Xpath under matches condition

Tags: regex, xslt, xpath, match

Given an XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mappings>
      <mapping match="/path/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/first/.*" value="value1" />
      <mapping match="/path/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/second/.*" value="value2" />
      <mapping match="/path/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/third/.*" value="value3" />
</mappings>
```

and a path `/path/2017/06/30/first/object.ext` as input, I'm searching for a way to select a specific `mapping` node where the `match` attribute matches the given path.

I've tried:

```
//mappings/mapping[matches($path,./@match)]/@value
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Suggestions?

Comment: Seems to work fine at http://xsltransform.net/a9GiwT.

Comment: This also works just fine for me in Oxygen XML, using the Saxon-HE 9.6.0.7 processor.  Note that the `matches()` function requires XSL 2.0 or newer.  XSL 1.0 has no support for `matches()`.  If your XSL processor does not support XSL 2.0 or newer, or if the `version` attribute on the topmost `xsl:stylesheet` element in your XSL code specifies `1.0`, your XPath expression will fail.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi, an XSLT 2.0 processor is needed but if you use it then the expression `//mappings/mapping[matches($path,./@match)]/@value` will work whether you have `version="2.0"` or `version="1.0"`, unless the XSLT 2.0 processor does not implement backwards-compatible behaviour. For instance Saxon 9.6 or 9.7 HE will evaluate that expression just fine in a `version="1.0"` stylesheet. On the other 9.8 does refuse that with a message "XSLT 1.0 compatibility mode is not available in this configuration".

Comment: @MartinHonnen, are we talking about the same things?  There's the `version` on the `<?xml?>` declaration, and the `version` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element.  If I set the latter to `version="1.0"`, Saxon refuses to process the XSL, throwing up the error `Unknown system function: matches`.  Do other processors handle this differently?  Or perhaps this is an artifact of how Oxygen XML behaves?

Comment: Saxon 9.6 or 9.7 HE do implement https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#backwards and certainly do support and execute `matches` in a `version="1.0"` stylesheet. Saxon 9.8 HE does not support https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#backwards-1.0 and will therefore not run a `version="1.0"` stylesheet. If you get an "unknown system function: matches" with Saxon then I think you use Saxon 6.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: That must be Oxygen "helping", then -- I've explicitly chosen Saxon-HE 9.6.0.7 in the processor selector dropdown, but if I set the `version` to `1.0` and view the error details, sure enough, it lists `Engine name: Saxon 6.5.5`.  Thank you for the additional information on compatibility behavior!